# multiple validators triggered in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Hi I am having a few validators in my angular form. this is how it looks. I am using Validators.compose to add a few custom validators. The validator errors are then displayed on the html component. In my case what i wanted to achieve is when matchingValidator throws an error i don't want angular to execute other two validators.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
      {
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
        confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
      },
      {
        validator: Validators.compose([
          matchingValidator('password', 'confirmPassword'),
          passwordStrengthValidator('password', 'confirmPassword'),
          blacklistedPasswordValidator(
            'password',
            'confirmPassword',
            this.blacklistedPasswords
          )
        ])
      }
    );
```

validator code is as below

```
export function matchingValidator(
  passwordControlName = 'password',
  passwordConfirmControlName = 'passwordConfirm'
): ValidatorFn {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
    const passwordValue: string = formGroup.get(passwordControlName).value;
    const passwordConfirmValue: string = formGroup.get(
      passwordConfirmControlName
    ).value;

    if (passwordValue.length && passwordConfirmValue.length) {
      return passwordValue !== passwordConfirmValue
        ? { passwordConfirmation: true }
        : null;
    }

    return null;
  };
}
export function passwordStrengthValidator(
  passwordControlName = 'password',
  passwordConfirmControlName = 'passwordConfirm'
): ValidatorFn {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
    const passwordValue: string = formGroup.get(passwordControlName).value;
    const passwordConfirmValue: string = formGroup.get(
      passwordConfirmControlName
    ).value;

    if (
      passwordValue &&
      passwordConfirmValue &&
      passwordValue.localeCompare(passwordConfirmValue) === 0 &&
      passwordValue.length >= 8
    ) {
      if (
        !/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/.test(
          passwordValue
        )
      ) {
        return { invalidPasswordStrength: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
}

export function blacklistedPasswordValidator(
  passwordControlName = 'password',
  passwordConfirmControlName = 'passwordConfirm',
  blacklistedPasswords: string[]
): ValidatorFn {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
    const passwordValue: string = formGroup.get(passwordControlName).value;
    const passwordConfirmValue: string = formGroup.get(
      passwordConfirmControlName
    ).value;
    if (
      passwordValue &&
      passwordConfirmValue &&
      passwordValue.localeCompare(passwordConfirmValue) === 0 &&
      passwordValue.length >= 8
    ) {
      let found = false;
      found = blacklistedPasswords.some(element => element === passwordValue);

      if (found) {
        return { blacklistedPassword: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
```

my html code is as follows.

```
 <alert type="danger" dismissable="false" *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('passwordConfirmation')">
        {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.MATCHING_PASSWORDS' | translate }}
      </alert>

      <alert type="danger" dismissable="false" *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength')">
        {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.PASSWORD_STRENGTH_INVALID' | translate }}
      </alert>

      <alert type="danger" dismissable="false" *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('blacklistedPassword')">
        {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.PASSWORD_NOT_PERMITTED' | translate }}
      </alert>
```

so in short what i want is if formGroup.hasError('passwordConfirmation') is true i want to stop printing validation error from other two validator. 
how can i achieve this . appreciate any help i am new to angular js and typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your if check smarter:

```
<alert type="danger" dismissable="false" *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('passwordConfirmation') && !(formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength') || formGroup.hasError('blacklistedPassword'))">
    {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.MATCHING_PASSWORDS' | translate }}
  </alert>
```

I showed one example above, but be careful here. If all three are true then you won't show any error. I would suggest only checking the other errors for all but one of your possible error types to prevent that problem.

FYI there is an easier way to reach the errors using a formControlName on your input, [see the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).

Comment: the problem with this solution is if i am having two of the conditions return true the error is not displayed . is there any solutions like if else if else using *ngif

Comment: You're correct, I fixed the boolean logic to not show if either of the other two have an error.

Comment: <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('passwordConfirmation') else second">
        <alert type="danger" dismissable="false">
          {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.MATCHING_PASSWORDS' | translate }}
        </alert>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container #second *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength') else third">
        <alert type="danger" dismissable="false">
          {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.PASSWORD_STRENGTH_INVALID' | translate }}
        </alert>
      </ng-container>